# Minimum bit wise OR of weights between source and destination in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

Given a weighted and un-directed graph with n vertices and m edges, where **1 <= n <= 1000** and **1 <= m <= 10000**. There can be multiple edges between two nodes of a graph with different weights.

Given a source and a destination, how to find the minimum distance between source and destination? Here distance is defined as the **bit-wise OR** of the weights of edges involved in the path.

Answer (score 1):

### Hint 1

Try working out the bits of the minimum distance in turn.

### Hint 2

Can you work out if there is a path which has bit x clear?

### Hint 3

Try removing edges from the graph if the weight has bit x set.

### Hint 4

Try seeing if there is a path with bit 31 set to 0.

If not, see if there is a path with bit 30 set to 0.

If there is, try seeing if there is a path with bit 31 and bit 30 set to 0, etc.

Answer (score 0):

While it may not be the most efficient algorithm, I would implement a best-first search on the graph. Create a priority queue that's going to contain the vertices to be explored next, only containing the source initially, with a 0 priority.

Then begin a loop that gets the lowest priority element from the list, explores all of its neighbors, and adds them into the queue, stopping when it finds the destination vertex or when the queue is empty.